# Dynamic Horizon: Interactive List with Edge Fades in white background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of items. At both ends of my list when there is still some content that isn't preset yet on the page I want it to fade out like how it does for youtube
[image: fade]
Mine currently looks like [image: My list]

```js
const scrollArea = document.getElementById('scroll-area');
const leftArrow = document.getElementById('scroll-left');
const rightArrow = document.getElementById('scroll-right');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

function toggleArrows() {

  if (scrollArea.scrollLeft === 0) {
    leftArrow.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    leftArrow.style.display = 'block';
  }

  if (scrollArea.scrollWidth - scrollArea.clientWidth - 1 <= scrollArea.scrollLeft) {
    rightArrow.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    rightArrow.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', toggleArrows);

scrollArea.addEventListener('scroll', toggleArrows);

document.getElementById('scroll-left').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const scrollArea = document.getElementById('scroll-area');
  scrollArea.scrollBy({
    left: -200,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});

document.getElementById('scroll-right').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const scrollArea = document.getElementById('scroll-area');
  scrollArea.scrollBy({
    left: 200,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
  toggleArrows();
});

scrollArea.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  startX = e.pageX - scrollArea.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = scrollArea.scrollLeft;
});

scrollArea.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
});

scrollArea.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
});

scrollArea.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - scrollArea.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX) * 2;
  scrollArea.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
});


function toggleFadeEffects() {
  const maxScrollLeft = scrollArea.scrollWidth - scrollArea.clientWidth;

  // Toggle the 'fade-in' class based on the scroll position
  if (scrollArea.scrollLeft > 0) {
    scrollArea.classList.add('fade-in');
  } else {
    scrollArea.classList.remove('fade-in');
  }

  // Since the ::after pseudo-element indicates there is more content to the right,
  // you should check whether we're at the very end of the scroll area to hide the fade effect.
  if (scrollArea.scrollLeft < maxScrollLeft) {
    scrollArea.classList.add('fade-in');
  } else {
    scrollArea.classList.remove('fade-in');
  }
}

// Initial check
toggleFadeEffects();

// Event listener for the scroll event
scrollArea.addEventListener('scroll', toggleFadeEffects);

document.getElementById('scroll-left').addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollArea.scrollBy({
    left: -200,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
  setTimeout(toggleFadeEffects, 200); // Use a timeout to give the scroll action time to complete
});

document.getElementById('scroll-right').addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollArea.scrollBy({
    left: 200,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
  setTimeout(toggleFadeEffects, 200); // Use a timeout to give the scroll action time to complete
});
```

```css
.content-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 90px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#scroll-right:hover,
#scroll-left:hover {
  background-color: #d8d8d8;
}

#scroll-right,
#scroll-left {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  background: transparent;
}

#scroll-right {
  right: 1%;
}

#scroll-left {
  left: 5.5%;
}

#scroll-area {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#scroll-area::before,
#scroll-area::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100px;
  /* Width of the fading effect */
  pointer-events: none;
}

#scroll-area::before {
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, transparent 100%);
}

#scroll-area::after {
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ffffff 0%, transparent 100%);
}

#scroll-area::before,
#scroll-area::after {
  display: none;
}

#scroll-area ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#scroll-area ul li {
  margin-right: 0px;
  padding: 2px 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  font-family: "Roboto", "Arial", sans-serif;
  ;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-bar">
  <button id="scroll-left"><</button>
  <div id="scroll-area">
    <ul>
      <li>All</li>
      <li>Music</li>
      <li>Sports leagues</li>
      <li>Romantic comedies</li>
      <li>Dramedy</li>
      <li>Gaming</li>
      <li>Fashion shows</li>
      <li>Live</li>
      <li>Cristiano Ronaldo</li>
      <li>Lionel Messi</li>
      <li>News</li>
      <li>Basketball</li>
      <li>Trailers</li>
      <li>Computer programming</li>
      <li>Podcasts</li>
      <li>Recently uploaded</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button id="scroll-right">></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried using ChatGBT but it gave me the toggleFadeEffects effects function and some other CSS styling like the pseudo elements with the gradients and that didn't work. Before that, I thought I could use box shadow on the buttons if big enough could may be cover up the edge and make it look like its fading out, but that didn't work either.